# What is missing from Silverlight 2's version of .Net?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I've just started developing in Silverlight 2 and have not run into any "missing parts" of .Net that I was using in the full version. Have you found anything to be missing from Silverlight 2's version of .Net that (1) you missed, (2) really needed, or (3) had to abandon Silverlight 2 because it was missing?

Answer (score 1):

I definately miss the VisualBrush, I got really use to that for Reflections and stuff and I miss that.  I also really miss the Bitmap Effects.  Dropshadows are crucial for creating RIAs and the solutions I've seen for Dropshadows are really bad hacks.

This is mostly from the XAML point of view though.

Answer (score 1):

The brushes have also been a pain in the neck for me.  Although the ImageBrush derives from the TileBrush, it doesn't actually have the ability to tile it's fill.  This makes texture mapping very difficult.  In addition, there are no base classes or interfaces available to create custom brush classes, so we just have to wait for this feature to become available in a future release.  Grrrrr.....

Other than that though, I have found the feature set to be very rich.  They've even added some great features like Dependency Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Consuming datasets/datatables, to bind them to objects or just use them.

I know they are missing on purpose, to reduce the deployed footprint of Silverlight, but that is a very important part of the framework, even in 2009.

System.Data mini version!